# Non-recursive 0/1 Knapsack algorithm using Breadth-first Search

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

I came across an interesting problem called Knapsack. You have a list of items, which all have a value and a weight. Then you have to find the combination of items that maximize the value of the objects summed, and stay within a certain limit. I saw somewhere that this is a search problem which you could use different search algorithms. Now I am trying to implement it with breadth-first.

The pseudo algorithm for BFS found on wikipedia is as follows:

```
Breadth-First-Search(Graph, root):

create empty set S
create empty queue Q      

root.parent = NIL
Q.enqueue(root)                      

while Q is not empty:
    current = Q.dequeue()
    if current is the goal
        return current
    for each node n that is adjacent to current:
        if n is not in S:
            add n to S
            n.parent = current
            Q.enqueue(n)
```

I have really tried to understand how to apply this to the knapsack problem.

As much as I understand, it's about building a tree. I need to expand and explore each node of one level at a time. For BFS I need a FIFO queue. For each item selected, I have two choices: Either I take the item or not.
Anyway, to be specific: What I do not understand, in my context, with the pseudo code above are:

- When I select an item, do I push it twice to the queue and mark one of them as used and one as not used?
- How do I know if the current is the goal? I assume its something like when there are no more nodes to explore which means we are at a leaf node.. But there will be many leaf nodes, so which one do I choose and how?
- What is meant with adjacent to current? If I only have a list, or an array of items (items have an ID, a weight, and a value), how do I know which is adjacent?

Comment: The major flaw of your thinking is that you miss out what the graph you traverse is. The graph you want to traverse it the one of all possible subsets of the input-set. So two subsets are adjacent, if they differ by exactly one item. `if current is the goal` comes from the usual use of BFS, which is to search for a specific node in a graph (e.g.: path-search). In your case this doesn't apply, since a precise solution requires an exhaustive search of the entire graph. You can only terminate once there are no more nodes/subsets to traverse.

Comment: @Paul thanks for your comment! Now I understand that what I am creating is a tree with all possible combinations of solutions which fits into the bag.
So what I do now is that I do exactly as the pseudo code above. But I push two nodes (one to represent a taken item, and one for not taken item), instead of that for each-part. I also try to add current as their parent in order to extract the full path after the While loop has finished. Does it sound like i've got it now you think?

Comment: Not really. You should build a graph starting with a set containing an arbitrary selection of the items, say the empty set for e.g.. Now each node contains the same set as it's neighbour, except that you added or removed a single element from the set. You don't need to extract any paths. For example input-set = `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, n = `{2}` neighbours = `{{}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}`. Traverse this graph with DFS or BFS and extract the node with the most optimal solution. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41912756/4668606) summarizes what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have 4 different items. Then the graph you are searching is a hypercube like this (image by [Yury Chebiryak](http://yury.chebiryak.name/index.html)):

[image: Gray code hypercube]

The binary numbers at the nodes are all of the possible knapsacks, with a 0 in the *n*th place meaning item *n* is not in the knapsack, and a 1 meaning it is, so for example 0000 means an empty knapsack, 1001 means the knapsack containing the first item and the 4th item, and so on.

At each step you remove the current node from the queue, and if it isn't the goal, construct the adjacent nodes by finding all of the knapsacks differing from the current one by 1 item that you haven't visited already. So for example, if the current node is 1001, you would construct nodes 0001, 1101, 1011, and 1000. You then add these nodes to the queue.

The goal only has a meaning if you are looking for a "good enough" solution, rather than the best solution. To establish whether the current node is the goal you simply work out the value of the current knapsack and compare it to the goal value.

If you want the *best* solution, then breadth first search is not helping you because you need to explore every node in the graph. [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) or [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) (which is a kind of [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)) would allow you to reduce the search space.

If you want a "good enough" solution, then FIFO [branch-and-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) or [hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) (starting from a random knapsack) are effective ways of using breadth-first search.

Comment: thank you for your response! I just wanted to reply to let you know that I did not understand it fully yet. But I will try to look more into it once I get the chance. What I want to find is the best combination, but I dont care about complexity. If that is what you mean by good enough. When you write best solution, do you refer to the solution which is not as memory bound (right term?) as the BFS?

Comment: By "best solution" I meant the optimum knapsack. You can either look for the optimum knapsack - which from your comment I realise now you want to do - or you can look for a "good enough" knapsack. To find the optimum knapsack you need to visit every node, so it doesn't matter whether you use BFS or DFS.